# How to style mui v5 select menu directly from styled component rather than SX or menu props?

Tags: material-ui

How can I style the MUI v5 select menu directly from a styled component rather than using SX or menu props? If I declare it inside the styled component, it doesn't take any effect, I don't want to use the sx props in this case ?

```js
interface ExtendedSelectProps extends SelectProps {
onChange: (event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>, child: ReactNode) => Promise<void>;
}

const StyledDataSelect = styled(Select)<ExtendedSelectProps>(({ theme }) => ({
// Style the menu inside the Select component
'& .MuiMenu-paper': {
backgroundColor: 'orange',
},
}));

<StyledDataSelect
variant='standard'
name='selectTrainingWeek'
disabled={disabled}
// // // MenuProps={{
// // //  sx: {
// // //  // // MuiMenu-paper
// // //  // '& .MuiMenu-paper': {
// // // backgroundColor: 'orange',
// // //  // },
// // // }}
value={value}
onChange={onChangeFn}
displayEmpty
>
```

Answer (score 0):

MUI Select uses [MuiPopover](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/) to display menu options. MuiPopover is neither a sibling nor a descendant of the root element used for Select. This makes it difficult to use **styled**. The MuiPopover root element is added to and removed from the DOM dynamically and visually positioned near Select.

You can style the menu by creating a theme and using MUI [theme style overrides](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides).

Sample code is below. See a [demo of the sample code](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-77506820).

In the sample, `yourId` is an *id* you assign to the Select component. `menu-` is automatically added as a prefix to the *id* of the MuiPopover root element when the MuiPopover is created. So, `menu-` must be added to the style override to avoid affecting other MuiPopovers.

### Sample code: main.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import { Box, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

interface MySelectOption {
    value: string;
}

type MySelectOptionList = MySelectOption[];

const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

let root;
if ( container != null ) {
    root = createRoot( container );
} else {
    throw new Error( 'Missing container element.' );
}

const theme = createTheme( {
    components: {
        MuiPopover: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    [`&#menu-yourId .MuiPaper-root.MuiMenu-paper.MuiPopover-paper`]: {
                        backgroundColor: 'orange'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} );

function App() {
    const [ value, setValue ] = React.useState( 'One' );

    const menuOptions: MySelectOptionList = [
        { value: 'One' },
        { value: 'Two' },
        { value: 'Three' },
        { value: 'Four' },
        { value: 'Five' }
    ];

    function handleChange( e: SelectChangeEvent ) {
        if ( e?.target?.value !== null ) {
            setValue( e.target.value );
        }
    }

    function buildOptions( option: MySelectOption ): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <MenuItem
                key={ option.value }
                id={ option.value }
                value={ option.value }
            >
                { option.value }
            </MenuItem>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Box component='form'>
            <Select
                id='yourId'
                name='yourId'
                value={ value }
                onChange={ handleChange }
            >
                { menuOptions.map( buildOptions ) }
            </Select>
        </Box>
    );
}

root.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
        <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```